# Inappropriate blocking method call

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, okhttp, kotlin-coroutines

this warning appears even when used with IO context.
my code:

```
override fun download(url: String, file: File): Flow<Long> = flow {
        var total: Long = 0
        var count: Long = 0

        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val client = OkHttpClient()
            val req = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
            val response = client.newCall(req).**execute**()
            val sink: BufferedSink = Okio.buffer(Okio.**sink**(file))

            response.body()?.let {
                while (count != -1L) {
                    count = it.source().**read**(sink.buffer(), 2048)
                    if (count == -1L) break
                    sink.**emit**()
                    total = total.plus(count)
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                        emit(total.times(100).div(it.contentLength()))
                    }
                }
            }
            sink.**close**()
        }
    }
```

the bold parts are getting warning. is anything going wrong with code or the warning should not appear?

Comment: It should be `flowOn(Dispatchers.Default)` if you are emitting on `Dispatchers.Default`. But the function that uses it can change that, as you are doing, leading to an error when it emits.

Comment: @Tenfour04 yes. it can lead to error. but question is not about it. even deleting that emit code, warnings still are there.

Comment: I think it's a false positive warning, but not 100% sure so I don't want to leave it as an answer.

Comment: Another issue I think is closing the sink after suspend function calls, because then it will never be closed if the coroutine is cancelled. Need to put it in a `finally` block or use `use`.

Comment: Whats a false positive warning?

Comment: A bug in the linter showing the warning when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

These method calls can throw an IOException and are called inside a suspend method.  These are flagged as likely blocking calls which they are.  The subtleties of the Dispatchers.IO is missed by the compiler warnings.

Your best bet is generally to either switch to the async mode using enqueue(), or put this behind a library function that hides these warnings.  A library like https://github.com/gildor/kotlin-coroutines-okhttp can also be helpful in bridging between blocking code in OkHttp and coroutines.